# Passing array to function for memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, memory, malloc

I have a problem with this code:

Main():

```
...
int main()
{

    int i=0, choice=0;

    int *array_val=NULL;

    while((choice=menu_sort())!=9)
    {

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            i=ins_val(&array_val, i);
            break;
....
```

I call the `ins_val()` function from another source:

```
int ins_val(int **array_val, int i)
{

    int j=0, add=0, k=0;

    system("cls");

    printf("Number to add: ");
    scanf("%d", &add);

    i++;

    reall(array_val, i);

    *array_val[i-1]=add;

    for (j=(i-1); j>0; j--)
    {

        if (*array_val[j]<(*array_val[j-1]))
        {

            k=(*array_val[j-1]);
            *array_val[j-1]=(*array_val[j]);
            *array_val[j]=k;

        }

    }

    return i;

}
```

and

```
void reall(int **array_val, int i)
{

    int *arr=NULL;
    arr=malloc(sizeof(int)*i);

    int j=0;

    for (j=0; j<i-1; j++)
    {

        arr[j]=(*array_val[j]);

    }

    int size=(sizeof(int)*i);

    free(*array_val);

    (*array_val)=(int*)malloc(size);

    if ((*array_val)!=NULL)
    {

        for (j=0; j<i-1; j++)
        {

            (*array_val[j])=arr[j];

        }

        free(arr);

    }

    else
    {

        ...

    }

    return;

}
```

I want to create a dynamic array where I can save values and order them.

My problem is that the memory allocation, because I can save only one value in the `array_val` array, even if with the `malloc()` I allocate `sizeof(int)*i`, so when I try to save a second value I get an error.

Comment: `*array_val[j]` --> `(*array_val)[j]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your assigments from:

```
(*array_val[j])=arr[j];
```

to:

```
(*array_val)[j] = arr[j];
```

Also, you have two loops that are missing an index:

```
for (j=0; j<i-1; j++)
```

This should be:

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
```

But the segfault is because `*array_val = NULL` when you pass it to `ins_val()`. This code in `reall()` needs to change from:

```
for (j=0; j<i-1; j++)
{

    arr[j]=(*array_val[j]);

}

int size=(sizeof(int)*i);

free(*array_val);
```

to something like this:

```
if (*array_val) {
        for (j=0; j<i; j++)
            arr[j]=(*array_val)[j];
        free(*array_val);
    }

    int size=(sizeof(int)*i);
```

In this loop, you were attempting to dereference a null pointer, since `*array_val` is NULL at first.